# Using “proposition on sum series” to find nature of series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following proposition:
Let $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {a_n}$, $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {b_n}$, $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$ with $c_n=a_n+b_n$ be infinite series.
Then:

- If both $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {a_n}$, $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {b_n}$ converge at $A, B\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$ converges at $C=A+B$.
- If both diverge at $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, then $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$ diverges at $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively.
- If one converges and the other is irregular, then $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$ is irregular.
- If one converges and the other one diverges at $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, then $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$ diverges at $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively.
- For the other cases we can’t come to a conclusion on the nature of  $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {c_n}$: one irregular and the other divergent, two divergent but with $\infty$ of different sign (one at $+\infty$ and the other one at $-\infty$), two irregular.

**MY QUESTION**

Does this mean that, given a series $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {d_n}$ of which we have to find the nature, we can write two series, one with term $e_n$ and the other one with term $f_n=d_n-e_n$, calculate $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {e_n}$ and $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {f_n}$ and then apply the theorem and see if it gives us any result?

I’m wondering that because maybe, by doing this, we can try to find $e_n$ so that $f_n$ is a known series (that we know how to solve), and $e_n$ is a simple one, and thus solving  $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {d_n}$ as  $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {e_n}+  \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} {f_n}$ might be simplier.

Is this method of finding nature of a series actually used? Could someone tell me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if we assume that $\sum_n^\infty e_n$ converges. Consider for example : $d_n= 0$ $\forall n$ and $e_n=\frac 1n$. Then $$\sum^\infty_nd_n=0 \text { but } \sum^\infty_n(d_n-e_n)=\sum^\infty_n-\frac1n=-\infty \text{ and } \sum^\infty_n e_n=+\infty$$
so that $-\infty+\infty $ is not $0$.

Also, it must of course be used cleverly depending on the situation. A toy example : $d_n=\frac 1n, e_n=\frac 1{n^2}$. We have that $$\sum^\infty_ne_n=\frac {\pi^2}{6} \text{ but is } \sum^\infty_nd_n-e_n=\sum^\infty_n \frac{1}n-\frac{1}{n^2} \text{ really easier to deal with ?}$$

Comment: Doesn’t it apply for all cases where the theorem gives us information? For example also if $e_n$ and $f_n$ both diverge at $-\infty$ or $+\infty$? And from your answer, it seems to me that it really isn’t a method very used, am I correct?

Comment: In fact all cases described by the theorem are valid when you apply them to your decomposition. However, the problem is that you will be now facing the difficulty of finding the nature of $f_n$ which might not simplify the problem. To be honest, I never saw this method being used but it is correct so might be useful when appropriate.

Comment: perfect, thanks for your answer.